# ElasticSearch - Phrase Suggestor

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using ElasticSearch and I have the following index mapping:

```
post  /my_index
{ 
  "mappings": {
    "medical_terms": {
      "properties": {
        "terms": {
          "type":     "string"
        }
      }
    }
  }
} 

PUT my_index/medical_terms/1
{
  "term":   "Paracetamol tablets"
}

POST /my_index/_search?search_type=count
{
  "suggest" : {
    "text" : "paracetmo tabelts",
    "simple_phrase" : {
      "phrase" : {
        "field" : "term",
        "size" : 1,
        "real_word_error_likelihood" : 0.95,
        "max_errors" : 0.5,
        "gram_size" : 2,
        "highlight": {
          "pre_tag": "<em>",
          "post_tag": "</em>"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

How do I get the phrase suggestor to return "paracetamol tablets" at the moment it returns:

```
"suggest": {
  "simple_phrase": [
     {
        "text": "paracetmo tabelts",
        "offset": 0,
        "length": 17,
        "options": [
           {
              "text": "paracetmo tablets",
              "highlighted": "paracetmo <em>tablets</em>",
              "score": 0.24901225
           }
        ]
     }
  ]
```

Do I need to use a custom analyzer and a dictionary?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is the `"max_errors" : 0.5,` parameter. If you set it to `0.8` it returns your expected result. I can't really explain you why 0.8 works because actually 0.5 means 50% of the terms can be written wrong and that is your usecase but somehow it works with 0.8. Maybe ask with that information in the elasticsearch usergroup?