# Phrase suggester Elasticsearch not correcting two words

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

I have the following mapping to my phrase suggester:

```
{
   "settings": {
      "analysis": {
         "analyzer": {
            "suggests_analyzer": {
               "tokenizer": "standard",
               "filter": [
                  "lowercase",
                  "asciifolding",
                  "shingle_filter"
               ],
               "type": "custom"
            }
         },
         "filter": {
            "shingle_filter": {
               "min_shingle_size": 2,
               "max_shingle_size": 6,
               "type": "shingle"
            }
         }
      }
   },
   "mappings": {
      "sample_data": {
         "properties": {
            "name": {
               "type": "string",
               "analyzer": "suggests_analyzer"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

I have "lung cancer", "colorectal cancer", "breast cancer" indexed in my index. But when I query for a mispelt query where both words are mispelt like "lhng cancar" returns zero results when I use the collate functionality. My sample query is as follows.

```
{
   "suggest": {
      "text": "lhng cancar",
      "simple_phrase": {
         "phrase": {
            "field": "name",
            "size": 5,
            "real_word_error_likelihood": 0.95,
            "max_errors": 0.5,
            "direct_generator": [
               {
                  "field": "name",
                  "suggest_mode": "always",
                  "size": 5

               }
            ],
            "collate": {
               "query": {
                  "inline": {
                     "match_phrase": {
                        "{{field_name}}": "{{suggestion}}"
                     }
                  }
               },
               "params": {
                  "field_name": "name"
               },
               "prune": false
            }
         }
      }
   },
   "size": 0
}
```

The response to the above query is:

```
{
   "took": 17,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 5,
      "successful": 5,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 1868381,
      "max_score": 0,
      "hits": []
   },
   "suggest": {
      "simple_phrase": [
         {
            "text": "lhng cancar",
            "offset": 0,
            "length": 11,
            "options": []
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

What changes do need to do in the query so that I get the expected result as "lung cancer" in the suggestions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ElasticSearch - Phrase Suggestor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32011110/elasticsearch-phrase-suggestor)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Raising the parameter of `max_errors: 2` solved my problem.

Answer (score 3):

You have to raise `max_errors` to 0.8 or more.

Same answer is given here
[ElasticSearch - Phrase Suggestor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32011110/elasticsearch-phrase-suggestor)

Comment: this is the correct answer, `max_error` is a float value ranges between `0...1`.: [Source](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-suggesters-phrase.html)